# Simple capacitance sensor on PCB - how to draw?

Tags: capacitor, pcb, pcb-design, circuit-design

I have implemented simple soil moisture sensor and now I would like to create PCB for it (I have prepared couple of prototypes using waterproof marker).

My general question is, what is the right way to draw something like this

[image]

using for ex CircuitMaker as a part of bigger PCB which will also have active elements.

Should I create custom element with this shape for pads (which is not very good because custom element have fixed size, every time I will change size of PCB for my project I will be forced to redraw it) ? Is there a way to do "free drawing" of pcb on the board when performing routing ?

Could you be so kind to direct me to the right approach here ?

Comment: I would draw that using two polygons. Or you could use individual polygons for the "spine" and each of the "tines".

Comment: You mean [this](https://documentation.circuitmaker.com/display/CMAK/PCB_Obj-PolygonPour((Polygon+Pour))_CM)? Is it possible to represent such object created as two polygons on the schematic ? One shape will be connected to ground, which is fine, but the other one needs to be connected to the specific place of the circuit. Can you advise how to represent that ?

Comment: When laying out the PCB, you may have to disable or ignore Design Rule Check errors when making this sort of pattern, or other things that can't easily be shown on a schematic.